# Allowing Flash Player even though its insecure

Tags: vpn, flash

Sorry but since "add a comment" only brought up a sign-up-window this will be a new question.

It is again about allowing flash content to be played within the TOR-Browser. Every one just answers it would be insecure and thus is blocked even if the plugin is enabled and the player installed. Flash may leak the IP-Adress.. to whom? The flash site itself might get to know who I am, but the provider of the internet I'm using will not. And that is still some kind of anonymity wished for as long as flash is still around.

So one answer is 'go VPN instead'. But why do you want to kick out flash users from the TOR-Community? The whole idea was to get lots of people using TOR for normal reasons so that whistleblowers for example can hide in that crowd. And what is a more normal use of internet/TOR than browsing for porn? As long as the NSA-Buildings we all got to see in the Snowden-News are not hosting a majority of all porn content to get the real identity of TOR-Users that porn surfing crowd is helping to hide other more critical guys.

I do think blocking flash is a terrible decision. Warning about Flash is enough. Also No-Script can be just deactivated allowing Java-Scripts leaking the IP adress and no one is blocking that. It just works the way flash used to work in TOR.
Just allow everything every normal web browsing user would expect to work. And allow to go back to full-safe-mode with one click. And that's it. Security for the ones who require it, Comfortability for the crowd protecting that kind of dudes and porn for the ones takeing a break from being full secure without haveing to rely on another product (VPN).

Answer (score 1):

> Flash may leak the IP-Address... to whom?

To whoever you're trying to hide from in the first place. The website will load through Tor, but Flash Player does not obey proxy rules, and will make a direct connection to the website.

Once Flash Player makes a direct connection to the website, it doesn't matter if you're using Tor. Your ISP, the website owners, and even someone on the same Wi-Fi network can see the direct connection from Flash Player, and figure out what website you're going to, and possibly see what you're watching in Flash Player.

Alas, since this is a question-and-answer website, there is a way to use Flash Player through Tor. With the Tor Browser open, go to your personal browser, and change the proxy settings to use a SOCKS5 proxy at `127.0.0.1:9150`.

Alternatively, with a little more configuration, you can install `tor` and configure it to only run as a local proxy.